# strange output of `strlen` when calculating the length of string which is stored in a char array

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, strlen

The code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char a[2] = "aa";
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(a)); //8
    return 0;
}
```

Why it outputs `8` instead of `2`?

Gcc version:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Nothing strange about it, just undefined behavior when you use `strlen()` with a character array that's not a valid string. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Also `g++` and `clang++` will refuse to compile this giving an `initializer-string for array of chars is too long` error.

Comment: @droptop if I let `char a[1] = "aa"` then the compiler will give me an error, but `char a[2] = "aa"` compiles successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char a[2] = "aa";
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(a)); //8
    return 0;
}
```

`strlen` requires a zero-terminated string. The 2-element char array `a` is not zero terminated, since you didn't provide space for the zero. So `strlen` keeps on counting until it runs into a zero somewhere. In your case it happened to be 6 bytes past the end of the `a` array. In all cases, access even to one element past the end (i.e. to `a[2]` - the third element here) is undefined behavior and may manifest in many more-or-less-entertaining ways (or sometimes hair-rising, too).

There are two fixes (at least), depending on what was your intent:

1. Make the array at least 3 elements long: it will then fit the zero terminator, and `strlen` will be able to stop counting before falling off the end of the array.
2. Keep the array 2 elements long. But since the array has a fixed size, use `sizeof(a)` instead of `strlen(a)`. `sizeof` determines the size of the array at compile time, since the information about the actual size doesn't really leave the compiler. By the time the program is done compiling and gets to run, it can't safely determine that size anymore - if you keep `a` two characters long and use `strlen`, that is. Then `sizeof` is the *only* way to provide the program with that information (or by using a magic constant, i.e. sticking another "2" or its equivalent somewhere else).

Comment: I don't think this is undefined behaviour. There is a deterministic rule that explains the `8` obtained on running the program (if it was undefined running it multiple times or on different machines will yield different outputs).

Comment: Maybe an explanation based on `clang`'s implementation of `strlen` is the way to go

Comment: @droptop Undefined behavior is abstract from any implementation. It's something that you determine by taking the code and the standard to a beach. Implementation doesn't figure in that. The "deterministic rule" you allude to is commonly called "a hack". It's not a rule you should care about, since it's useless. This behavior may well change tomorrow. Or when you switch between debug and release mode. Or whatever. Many compilers special-case `strlen` and don't treat it as a regular function, similarly to `memcpy` - they inline it and constant propagate into it.

Comment: The `strlen` you get when passing `char[2]` to it may well be different from `strlen` you get when passing a string the compiler can't presume anything about. And so on - you simply cannot take such things for granted, since modern optimizers are very likely to break this. I'd say that what you describe is a missed optimization opportunity. A compiler could statically deduce that this is undefined behavior and remove the call to `strlen`, and probably all successor and preceding code, since it wouldn't be legal to enter into that code block. C++ compilers do this, subject to aliasing rules.

Comment: @droptop: Re “if it was undefined running it multiple times or on different machines will yield different outputs”: That is false. In the definition of the C standard, *undefined behavior* means the C standard does not impose any requirements on the behavior. It does not mean the behavior must be random, must be varying, or must be different in different implementations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok it's undefined behaviour. great. But why isn't it random? Wouldn't you expect reading past a contiguous array to be random?? I think a satisfactory answer will explain why we get that `8`, even if the answer is based on a particular `strlen`  implementation

Comment: @droptop: No, I would not expect it to be random. If the compiler is not optimizing away the allocation for `a`, then the program runs in the same way every time: The program loader sets up a new stack, likely with zero-filled pages, and loads memory with the program code and initialized data, then starts execution at the program entry point. The startup routine there initializes the C environment and calls `main`. `main` sets up its stack frame, including the memory for `a`. All of that code runs exactly the same way each time, so it gets exactly the same result…

Comment: … Modern systems commonly use address space layout randomization. That randomizes the location of stack in memory and the locations of certain other things, so randomness is deliberately introduced into programs to foil attackers. However, that does not affect any behavior in this simple case. So it is not random.

Comment: @droptop, just run on linux ubuntu (intel, 64bit) and it printed `2`.  So your assertion of resulting in the same value printed (8) in every machine where the program is run is false.

Comment: @droptop, undefined behaviour doesn't mean random behaviour.  Undefined can be random or can be fixed.  Undefined is preciselly that, undefined.ç